# run project after cloning it in pycharm

Tags: git, pycharm

I just cloned a repository from GitHub in pycharm and while running the project it is running the test why I cannot run the project?
[image of pychary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8LVn.png)
[image of pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3M1n.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshots, it seems like PyCharm **is** running the project using your "**Test**" run configuration. It's not running the "main" module because the run configuration is looking for tests. It finds no tests, so then it stops.

A **run configuration** tells PyCharm *how* to run a project. In this case, it's telling it to run the project's tests and use a python testing module to do so.

[Run/Debug Configuration PyCharm documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration.html).